# Public desktop is not shown anymore since Windows 10 redstone

Tags: windows-10

Since I upgraded to Windows 10 anniversary (redstone) the content of C:\Users\Public\Desktop isn't shown anymore on users desktop, users only see their own desktop.

The permissions are okay (Read permission for Users group)
The public desktop folder is not empty and has the same shortcut it had before the update.

Comment: Can't repro this. Items in Public\Desktop shows up fine here. Checking the  User Shell Folders (HKLM) is a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is quite simple. In a elevated command window

SETX PUBLIC "Location of your Public rootfolder" /M

Logoff, Logon

Adhere to the naming of the public subfolders (Desktop, Documents etc)

Comment: Found out Microsoft changed the path in registry and created a new directory where default profile path was, but your command is interesting and I will document myself on it.